# How to understand Python's module lookup

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I created two new files, random.py and main.py, in the directory. The code is as follows:

```py
# random.py

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("random")
```

```py
# main.py

import random

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(random.choice([1, 2, 3]))
```

When I run the main.py file, the program reports an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(random.choice([1, 2, 3]))
AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'choice'
```

Main.py imports my own defined random module.

However, if I create a new sys.py file and a main.py file in the same directory, the code is as follows:

```py
# sys.py

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("sys")
```

```py
# main.py

import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sys.path)
```

When I run the main.py file, successfully.

main.py imports the built-in modules sys.

Why is there such a clear difference?

The directory relationship of the script file is as follows:

```
C:.
    main.py
    random.py
    sys.py
```

Thank you very much for your answer.
Forgive my poor english.

Comment: You made your own random module.  It has no choice.

Comment: Don't name your files the same as standard library modules

Comment: As described above, you created a module called `random`, which is in direct conflict with the [Python standard library `random` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html). Also, neither your own `random` module nor the Python standard library `random` module have any attribute `choice`, which is the crux of the exception.

Comment: I think OP already knows why there is a conflict. He wanted to know why it doesnt work for `random` but no problem for `sys`.

Comment: Naming your file name as `random.py` will make a conflict with `random` Python module.

Comment: @HenryYik Maybe I didn't make it clear. I really want to know why it doesn't work for random but there is no problem with sys

Comment: @D.J.Fly well i did understand what you are asking. And there are two nice answers below for your question.

Answer (score 4):

`sys` is a *built-in* module, meaning it's compiled directly into the Python executable itself. Built-in modules outprioritize external files when Python is looking for modules. The standard `random` module isn't built-in, so it doesn't get that treatment.

Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-meta-path):

> When the named module is not found in `sys.modules`, Python next searches `sys.meta_path`, which contains a list of meta path finder objects. These finders are queried **in order** to see if they know how to handle the named module...
>
> Python’s default `sys.meta_path` has three meta path finders, one that knows how to import built-in modules, one that knows how to import frozen modules, and one that knows how to import modules from an import path (i.e. the path based finder).

Since the finder for built-in modules comes before the finder that searches the import path, built-in modules will be found before anything on the import path.

You can see a tuple of the names of all modules your Python has built-in in [`sys.builtin_module_names`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names).

---

That said, while any built-in module would outprioritize a module loaded from a file, `sys` has its own special handling. `sys` is one of the foundational building blocks of Python, and much of the `sys` module's setup needs to happen before the import system is functional enough for the normal import process to work. `sys` gets explicitly created during interpreter setup in a way that bypasses the normal import system, and then future imports for `sys` find it in `sys.modules` without hitting any meta path finders.

How and where `sys` is created is an implementation detail that varies from Python version to Python version (and is wildly different in different Python implementations), but in the CPython 3.7.4 code, you can see it beginning on line 755 in [`Python/pylifecycle.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.4/Python/pylifecycle.c#L755).

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr Caching**

`sys` is somewhat of a special case among other python modules because it gets loaded at program start, unconditionally (presumably because a lot of the constants, functions, and data within - such as the streams `stdout` and `stderr` - are used by the python interpreter). As @user2357112 noted in the other answer, this is partly because it's built-in to the python executable, but also because it's necessary for running a substantial amount of python's core functionality (see below how it needs to be loaded for imports to work). `random` is part of the standard library, but it doesn't get loaded automatically when you execute, which is the primary relevant difference between it and `sys`, for our purposes

Looking at [python's documentation on the subject](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache) clarifies how python resolves imports:

> The first place checked during import search is `sys.modules`. This mapping serves as a cache of all modules that have been previously imported, including the intermediate paths.
>   ...
>   During import, the module name is looked up in `sys.modules` and if present, the associated value is the module satisfying the import, and the process completes. However, if the value is `None`, then a `ModuleNotFoundError` is raised. If the module name is missing, Python will continue searching for the module.

As for where it looks for the module, you can see in your observed behavior that it looks in the local directory first. That is, it searches the local directory first and then the "usual places" afterwards.

The reason for the discrepancy between how `sys` is handled and how `random` is handled is caching - `sys` is cached (so python doesn't even check the path to import), whereas `random` is not cached (so python does check the path to import it, and imports locally).

---

There are a few ways you can change this behavior.

First, if you *must* have a local module called `sys`, you can [use `importlib` to import it in relative or absolute terms](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module), without running into the ambiguity with the `sys` that's already cached. I have no idea how this would affect other modules that independently try to import `sys`, and you really shouldn't be naming your files the same as standard library modules anyway.

Alternatively, if you want the code to check python's built-in modules before checking the local directory, then you should be able to do that by modifying `sys.path`, which shows the order in which paths are searched for input (the same as the `$PATH` environment variable, or any other similar language-specific one). The first element of `sys.path` is usually going to be an empty string `''`, that would result in searching the current working directory. So you can simply move that to the back of `sys.path`, to have it searched last instead of first:

```
sys.path.append(sys.path.pop(0))
```

Comment: While `sys` is loaded at interpreter startup, not all built-in modules are automatically loaded. For example, `math` is built-in on non-Windows platforms, but it doesn't get loaded until something `import`s it.

Comment: That said, module caching is an important part of the story, and `sys` is loaded in a way unlike "normal" built-in modules. I don't think the normal finder for built-in modules is involved at all.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm not sure how one would test it, honestly, but `sys` is necessary to even check `sys.modules`, and of course `sys` is the first thing in `sys.modules` when you do check, so I think that's the reason for the discrepancy in this case.